# printing picture from database in rpt file vs2008

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, rpt

Good day everyone, I have a question. I want to print a picture from database. Now, I am using vs2008 rpt file. In parameter fields there is no image in value type. How do I do that. Feel free to downvote. I'm new in crystal report.

Comment: have you tried using google.com?

Comment: format your question. show some code snippet.